# how to get path from root to desired node i.e. includes first number as rooth then child -> child->upto parent of child

Tags: haskell, tree

```
t1 = Tree 1[ Tree 2  [  Tree 4[],  Tree 5 []  ], Tree 3[Tree 6 []]]

       1
      / \
     /   \
    2    3
   /\    /\
  /  \  /  \
 4   6  7   9
```

if asked for 9 it should return (True,[1,3]) (if exits)
if doesnt exist the should return   (False,[])

```
data Tree = Tree Int [Tree]  deriving (Show , Eq)

isPrsnt num (Tree nnum ls:xs) parents | (nnum==num) = (True,parents)  
                                      | (fst (isPrsnt num( ls ) (parents ++[nnum])) == False) = isPrsnt nnum xs (init parents)   
                                      | otherwise = isPrsnt nnum xs parents


isPrsnt num ([]) parents = (False,parents)
```

Comment: The types don't really match. Your description states `([Int], Bool)`, your code `(Bool, [Int])`. Why not `Maybe [Int]`?

Comment: Use `Maybe` instead of a tuple.

Comment: By the way, `t1` doesn't even contain `7` or `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why is the path to 9 in the given tree equal to [1,3]? Should it not be [1,1] - you go down the 1st branch from 1 to 3, and then the 1st branch again from 3 to 9.

Secondly, there may be 0 or more occurrences of any element in any tree - therefore, your function should return a list (which contains 0 or more occurrences of some type) of paths. You don't need an additional boolean - to check if there are no paths, check that the list is `null`.

```
type Path = [Int] 

paths :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> [Path]
```

The function itself is quite simple at the correct type:

```
paths a = go where 
  go (Tree b ts) = 
    [ [] | a == b ] ++ 
    concat [ map (i:) (go t) | (i,t) <- zip [0..] ts ]
```

The first line of `go` checks if the element `a` is at the root - if so, there is a path (namely the empty path) to that element. The second line checks the subtrees - first it associates each subtree with its index with `zip [0..]`, then it recurses on the subtree and extends each path in that subtree with the index of the subtree (`map (i:)`).

And finally:

```
member :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
member a t = not $ null $ paths a t
```